# focusing on the last input when adding an entry with a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When the inputs are focused, I make the borders red with css.
But I can't autofocus on the most recently added input.

codesandbox: [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-trick-adding-inputs-with-a-click-of-a-button-forked-ipggz0?file=/src/App.js:0-861)

```
import React from "react";

import "../src/styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { values: [] };
  }

  createUI() {
    return this.state.values.map((el, i) => (
      <div key={i} style={{ marginBottom: "1rem" }}>
        <style>
          {`
           .test:focus-within{
            border:3px solid red !important;
            }
          `}
        </style>
        <div className="test">
          <input type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
    ));
  }

  addClick() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ values: [...prevState.values, ""] }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.createUI()}
        <input
          type="button"
          value="add more"
          onClick={this.addClick.bind(this)}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

How can I autofocus the last added input and make its borders red?

Answer (score 1):

can create a useRef and assign it to the latest input

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { values: [] };
    this.lastRef = React.createRef();

  }

  createUI() {
    return this.state.values.map((el, i) => (
      .....
          <input ref={i === this.state.values.length - 1 ? this.lastRef : undefined} type="text" />
       ....
    ));
  }

  addClick() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ values: [...prevState.values, ""] }), 
    () => {
       this.lastRef.current.focus()
    });
    
  }
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-trick-adding-inputs-with-a-click-of-a-button-forked-tcfh4d)

Comment: it doesnt work. please check the demo.

Comment: it works fine. focus moves to new input and border get changed to red. double check

Comment: if(this.lastRef && this.lastRef.current) this.lastRef.current.focus();